# Using DateTime.ParseExact to get only the time (without the day)

Tags: .net, vb.net

I get unexpected results when I use DateTime.ParseExact. 
Here's my test code:

```
Dim MinVal As DateTime = #12:00:01 AM#
Dim MaxVal As DateTime = #11:59:59 PM#
Dim TooBig1, Equal1 As Boolean
Dim TooBig2, Equal2 As Boolean

Dim dt1 As DateTime = #12:00:01 AM#
Dim dt2 As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("12:00:01 AM", "hh:mm:ss tt", Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)

TooBig1 = (dt1.CompareTo(MaxVal) > 0)
Equal1 = (dt1.CompareTo(MinVal) = 0)

TooBig2 = (dt2.CompareTo(MaxVal) > 0)
Equal2 = (dt2.CompareTo(MinVal) = 0)
```

The result is fine for dt1:

- it shows in the debugger as #12:00:01 AM# (without the day)
- TooBig1 is False
- Equal1 is True

But the result is (wrong?) unexpected for dt2:

- it shows in the debugger as #9/30/2011 12:00:01 AM#
- TooBig2 is True
- Equal2 is False

It looks like it's because the day is systematically added by ParseExact even though I only specify the time in the format.

My question is: How can I read just the time with DateTime.ParseExact?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) states:

> If format defines a time with no date element and the parse operation succeeds, the resulting DateTime value has a date of `DateTime.Now.Date`.

If you want a time with no date, you can use:

```
var parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact(...);
var timeOnly = parsedDate - parsedDate.Date;
```

Comment: That becomes a `TimeSpan` object, though, not a `DateTime`. The fact you gloss over this important detail shows once again that the use of untyped variables is a terrible practice.

Comment: @Nyerguds: You're right that the result is a `TimeSpan`. Apparently that is what the OP wanted, or he quickly figured out how to create a new `DateTime` from it. There are no untyped variables in that code snippet; both are strongly typed, as the compiler would make abundantly clear the first time you tried to use `timeOnly` as a `DateTime`. Did you perhaps mean to say that taking advantage of type inference is a bad thing?

Comment: Yes, with "untyped" I meant "not specifically typed in the code", which indeed means type inference. This is a perfect example of it, too; it's not visible at all from that code that `DateTime` minus `DateTime` equals _not_ a `DateTime`.

Answer (score 2):

use [`dt1.TimeOfDay`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday.aspx) and [`dt2.TimeOfDay`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday.aspx) for such comparisons... thus taking the day part out of the equation...

Answer (score 2):

If you don't specify a day, it apparently assumes today. (Not unreasonable if you're writing, say, time-tracking software.)

If you just want the time portion, you could parse it like you're already doing, and then grab just the time-of-day portion:

```
' Existing code:
Dim dt2 As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact("12:00:01 AM", "hh:mm:ss tt", _
    Globalization.DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)
' Now grab just the time:
Dim ts2 As TimeSpan = dt2.TimeOfDay
```

That will be a `TimeSpan` instead of a `DateTime`, but if you don't actually *need* it as a DateTime, TimeSpan is more appropriate for something that's just hours/minutes/seconds but not days.

(You might also try using TimeSpan.ParseExact in the first place, but it isn't built to handle AM/PM, and would parse 12:00:01 as being 12 hours. So you probably do want DateTime.ParseExact followed by .TimeOfDay.)

---

If you actually *do* need to represent it as a DateTime -- with a date portion of, say, 1/1/0001 -- you could always convert that TimeSpan back to a DateTime manually:

```
Dim dt3 As New DateTime(1, 1, 1, ts2.Hours, ts2.Minutes, ts2.Seconds, ts2.Milliseconds)
```