# Convert Javascript time string to DateTime or TimeSpan in MVC Controller

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

How do I covert JavaScript string "5:00 PM" to DateTime or TimeSpan when it get send to the MVC controller. I am using

> bootstrap-timepicker

```
 // usage      
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#timepicker1').timepicker();
 </script>
```

Javascript payload

```
{
  Skip: 0
  Status: []
  Take: 15
  DueTime: "1:00 PM" // keep in mind that this is a string
}
```

Server Object would be something like

```
class TimeSheet
{
   public TimeSpan DueTime;
}
```

Comment: A `TimeSpan` is representative of a span between two times -- a delta or difference -- it is not meant to actually store point-in-time information. Your `DueTime` property should, IMO, be a `DateTime` struct. You could pass the string to the server and parse it on the server side using the method [shown in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7616261/using-datetime-parseexact-to-get-only-the-time-without-the-day).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `DateTime.Parse`. Convert on server(on controller) when your string would transmit with your time. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.datetime.parse(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: there should be a SO language filter that converts MSDN links to the locale of the logged in user :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I read everyhting wrong hence the deleted answer.. !

But I'm not giving up ;)

Your bootstrap-timepicker, will give you a time as this "1:00 PM".

But before that we are going to look on the serverside to see what we can parse into a datetime object.

This is C# for parsing datetime.

```
string dateString, format;  
DateTime result;
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

dateString = "15/08/2000 16:58"
format = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"
result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
```

Now as you se your string wont look like that I'm going to assume that you want **todays date**!

This is function I tend to use most of the times when converting, to 24H clock.

```
function ConvertTimeformat(str) {
    var time = str;
    var hours = Number(time.match(/^(\d+)/)[1]);
    var minutes = Number(time.match(/:(\d+)/)[1]);
    var AMPM = time.match(/\s(.*)$/)[1];
    if (AMPM == "PM" && hours < 12) hours = hours + 12;
    if (AMPM == "AM" && hours == 12) hours = hours - 12;
    var sHours = hours.toString();
    var sMinutes = minutes.toString();
    if (hours < 10) sHours = "0" + sHours;
    if (minutes < 10) sMinutes = "0" + sMinutes;

    //Creating the todays date in the right format
     var today = new Date();
     var dd = today.getDate();
     var mm = today.getMonth()+1;//January is 0!`
     var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
     if(dd<10){dd='0'+dd}
     if(mm<10){mm='0'+mm}
     var todaysdate = dd+'/'+mm+'/'+yyyy +" " ; //<--I added an extra space!
     var hoursNminutes = sHours + ":" + sMinutes
     //CREATE THE RIGHT FORMAT FOR DATE.PARSEXACT "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm"
      var dateToParse = todaysdate + hoursNminutes 
    return dateToParse;
}
```

To Use the function do like this!

```
//Call it and provide your bootstrap time. And make it return to a variable
var dateToBeSentToServer = ConvertTimeformat("1:00 PM");
//OR With the bootstraptime as a variable 
var dateToBeSentToServer = ConvertTimeformat(timevariable);
```

**Now you can send dateToBeSentToServer to your serverside for parsing**!

Comment: Could you explain how you're going to get from "1:00 PM" to epoch time?

Comment: I am using bootstrap-timepicker, would would I do it inside bootstrap function?

Comment: I don't want to send it to the server side as a string that just seems like a dirty work around.