# How do i save time from dropdownlist to database?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, timespan

my dropdown is like this
 [image: my dropdown is like this]

here iam storing selected value of dropdown into variable of type 'TimeSpan' and saving in database. But it gives exception: '**String was not recognized as a valid TimeSpan.**' my database  fieldtype is also Time(7)

```
 DateTime start_time = DateTime.ParseExact(starttime.SelectedItem.Text, "hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
 TimeSpan stt = start_time.TimeOfDay;
SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO IvrDatas starttime values @starttime",conn);
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@starttime", stt)
```

Please help me out in this matter.

Comment: How about reading the documentation for `TimeSpan.Parse`?

Comment: Yeah i did but couldn't find solution for my code

Comment: How can a single time value define a `TimeSpan`? Are you sure it's not `DateTime.Parse(starttime.SelectedItem.Text).Time` you're looking for?

Comment: i have edited my code according to ur suggestion but it gave exception of '*String was not recognized as a valid DateTime'  edited my post u can check it out @GigiSan

Comment: If you didn't solve the problem yet, try [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7616347/2898163)

Answer (score 1):

"11:00 AM" cannot be parsed with the TimeSpan.Parse function. You could use the ParseExact function as follows:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(starttime.SelectedItem.Text, "hh:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You can extract the time from the Parsed datetime with the ".TimeOfDay" function. That will give you the proper value and type

Comment: i should store ur above given line in variable of type DateTime? and field in database should also also be changed from time(7) to DateTime ? Right?

Comment: You can extract the time from the Parsed datetime with the ".TimeOfDay" function. That will give you the proper value and type

Comment: I tried ur suggestion but it gave exception:**String was not recognized as a valid DateTime** and edited my code also.. u can check if i did it correctly.

Comment: Then it's time to check the value of "starttime.SelectedItem.Text". It should of course not be "--Select--". Then it will not work of course